# Can we get current wallpaper image through react native?

Tags: android, react-native, wallpaper

I am making a demo in **react-native** for getting and changing wallpaper. I have been searching for an option to get the **current wallpaper** of the device but I did not find anything which is useful. All I can find is to **set wallpaper** to the device. But I need to get a wallpaper image that is already there.

**Note:** I am making this demo application only for android.

It would be great if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use WallpaperManager class for this.
more detailed information is available in the documentation
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager